With telerik:RadWizard in RadMultiPage large ViewState causes RadGrid refresh ViewState exception
For a version 7.3 of C#, ASP.Net Web Form app with .Net Framework 4.6.2
I have an ASPX with an ascx loaded with LoadControl
On the ascx, I have
<telerik:RadMultiPage
   <telerik:RadPageView 1
       <telerik:RadAjaxPanel
           <telerik:RadWizard
               - has async server calls at the end of a long process

If, at the end of long process you go to PageView 2 :
    <telerik:RadPageView 2
        <telerik:RadGrid 
             <CommandItemSettings ShowRefreshButton="true" ShowAddNewRecordButton="false" />
enter code here

and on this RadGrid, immediately after the long process, click the refresh icon
I get the 'Can't load ViewState' exception.
If I go there directly, without the long process, refresh works just fine.
I tried to solve this with my ASPX page trying to save ViewState to Session using:
private const string ViewStateKey = "WebApp_ViewState";

protected override void SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(object viewState)
{
    var viewStateId = (string)Session[ViewStateKey];
    if (viewStateId == null)
    {
        viewStateId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Session[ViewStateKey] = viewStateId;
    }

    LosFormatter formatter = new LosFormatter();
    using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        formatter.Serialize(writer, viewState);
        Session[viewStateId] = writer.ToString();
    }
}

protected override object LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
{
    var viewStateId = (string)Session[ViewStateKey];
    if (viewStateId != null)
    {
        string serializedViewState = (string)Session[viewStateId];
        if (serializedViewState != null)
        {
            LosFormatter formatter = new LosFormatter();
            using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(serializedViewState))
            {
                return formatter.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

But other issues cropped up like other ascx controls on other pages going completely readonly, and the telerik:RadGrid OnPageSizeChanged event causing some unknown Null Reference exception.
Is there a proper better way to deal with ViewState?
Make it bigger? With MaxPageStateFieldLength? That breaks it down into chunks, so how big should they be? Yes it's a performance hit...
Have a replacement that actually supports all required ViewState functionality?
